# How to duck and unduck Mediaplayer output in Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am implementing a new application that plays two songs with Media player. What I need to do is, I need to duck the first player output when the second player output is come in to the picture. And need to unduck the first player when second player was completed. Is this possible?

My code is as follows:

```
public class SampleMediaPlayerActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnPreparedListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
Button playSong;
MediaPlayer player1;
MediaPlayer player2;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    playSong = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playSongButton);
    playSong.setOnClickListener(this);
    player1 = MediaPlayer.create(SampleMediaPlayerActivity.this, R.raw.song);
    player1.setVolume(100.0f, 100.0f);
    player1.setOnPreparedListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Play song");
    //player1.setVolume(0.5, rightVolume)
    player2 = MediaPlayer.create(SampleMediaPlayerActivity.this, R.raw.song);
    player2.setVolume(100.0f, 100.0f);
    //player.
    player2.start();
}
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    player1.start();

}
}
```

Comment: Have you read [the Android documentation on ducking](http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/audio-focus.html#DUCK)?